# Regular expression to extract content within square brackets and parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Is there an expression I can use to extract the contents of both square brackets and parenthesis into a list or array? This is what I have, it extracts the full string in the parenthesis. I only want the text in the parenthesis.

```
String example = "[21](BULK(KIN[1[35]](MARK)))";    
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));    
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting and what output are you getting?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Lemme rephrase, do you need your output as `21BULKKIN135MARK` as a whole or `21` `BULK` `KIN` `1` `35` `MARK`?

Comment: 21 BULK KIN 1 35

Comment: When asked for clarification please edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should stand alone, in part because not all readers read all comments. When you give an example, *always* show the desired result (as a valid language construct). If, in addition, you show something you've tried that is not correct, show the result you got.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it do the trick by specifying which characters should be ignored and repeat that infinitely over the whole String like so:

```
[^\[\]\(\)]+
```

The `+` at the end avoids matching empty matches.
This will not check for correct setted brackets and braces though.

My code would be as follows:

```java
String example = "[21](BULK(KIN[1[35]](MARK)))";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\[\\]\\(\\)]+").matcher(example);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(0)+ " ");
}
```

The double backslash results from java using this character as escape character itself. Also note that I changed the print statement so it behaves as you described in your comments below your question.

Comment: As far as I understand the problem of questioner is, ee want extract letters **within** square brackes and parenthesis. Means without them.

Comment: This is exactly what my code does: It ignores all ```[```,```]```,```(``` and ```)```. Look at how my RegEx starts with ```[^``` - that tells it to search for anything that is not part of the specified characters between the ```[^``` and the last ```]```.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract only the parts consisting of letters, you could search for such:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)").matcher(example);
```

and then collect the matches in the while-loop.
Edit:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)").matcher(example);
```

extracts all word literals, including numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression to extract the strings of interest:

```
/(?<=\[|\()[^\[\]\(\)]+/x
```

For the string

```
"[21 is a winner](BULK(KIN[1[35]](MARK my man)))"
```

the matches against this regular expression would be `"21 is a winner"`, `"BULK"`, `"KIN"`, `"1"`, `"35"` and `"MARK my man"`.

The regular expression reads, "match one or more (`+`) characters other than (`^`) those in the string `'[]()'` (`[^\[\]\(\)]` being a *character class*), that is immediately preceded by `'('` or `'['` (`(?<=\[|\()` being a *positive lookbehind*).

It should be noted that the same result obtains if the string has unbalanced parentheses or brackets:

```
"[21 is a winner((BULK]KIN(1[35]](MARK my man[[["
```

The regular expression could be written to confirm the parentheses and brackets are balanced (using subexpressions), but it would be simpler to check that separately, if required. That could be done by creating an empty stack and then process the string character-by-character using the following rules:

- if the character is '(' or '[' push it onto the stack
- if the character is ')' and the stack is non-empty and the top character is '(', pop '(' off the stock; else parentheses are unbalanced
- if the character is ']' and the stack is non-empty and the top character is '[', pop '[' off the stock; else brackets are unbalanced
- if the character is not in the string "()[]" disregard it.
- if all characters in the string are processed, parentheses and brackets are balanced if and only if the stack is then empty.

Note that at any given time the stack contains only the characters `'('` and `'['`.